# ElasticSearch bool query request

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch, request, client

I am trying to translate this query to java code (HighLevelRestClient):

```
{
   "query":{
     "bool": {
       "must": [
         {
           "query_string": {
              "query": "((\"PUT\" OR \"POST\") AND \"REST\" AND (\"BRI\" OR \"BRIEXT\" OR \"TMP\"))"
            }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

I tried this request with postman and it works fine, And I want to try it with the elasticSearch resthighlevel client.

```
QueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must();
```

I don't know  what to put inside the must.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `queryStringQuery` method , as noted in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-full-text-queries.html)

The following code snippet uses the [high level RestClient](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html)

```
String query =  "((\"PUT\" OR \"POST\") AND \"REST\" AND (\"BRI\" OR 
 \"BRIEXT\" OR \"TMP\"))";

QueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(new 
QueryStringQueryBuilder(query));
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(matchQueryBuilder);

SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
// set the indices you want to search in.
searchRequest.indices("your-index");
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

// execute the query
SearchResponse response = hlRestClient.search(searchRequest, header);
SearchHits hits = response.getHits();
```

Comment: I tried this:

`String query = "((\"PUT\" OR \"POST\") AND \"REST\" AND (\"BRI\" OR \"BRIEXT\" OR \"TMP\"))";

  QueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(new QueryStringQueryBuilder(query));

  SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
  searchSourceBuilder.query(matchQueryBuilder);
  searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);`

But it doesn't work! I am getting a timeout exception.

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope it helps, please let me know if everything worked for you. Note that you have to set the high level client before you use it (host, port, protocol)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I am getting a timeout exception

Comment: Then you should check your client configuration. Something should be wrong about it. The code I posted has been tested with elasticsearch 6.1. Could you post the code where you initialize the rest client, as well as the stacktrace of the exception please?

Comment: this is the exception:
java.io.IOException: listener timeout after waiting for [30000] ms
 at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:663)
 at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:222)
 at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:194)
 at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:488)

As for initialization there is no problem.
Could I configure the timout time for the client ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with the setRequestConfigCallback method. There you can set the connectionRequestTimeout. Do you have many records saved? Does your entity contain a very large query?

Comment: finally I used asunchronous request and it works fine. thanks

Comment: Your question was how to form a "query_string" query, with the high level rest client. Could you please explain to me, why you unaccepted the answer? Your feedback is important to me.